# « Il y en a » ou « il y a »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Je n'arrive vraiment ni à comprendre la différence entre ces deux expressions ni à déterminer laquelle est correcte.

« **Il y en a**  des personnes qui proposent ce genre de choses. » ou « **il y a** des personnes qui proposent ce genre de choses. » ?

Quand est-ce qu'on ajoute **en**, et quelle modification apporte-t-il au sens de l'expression ?

Answer (score 3):

> Est-ce qu'il y a des bijoutiers au marché de Noël ?
>
> Oui, il y en a.
>
> Oui, il y en a deux.

"En" remplace le COD "des bijoutiers". On peut également préciser la quantité ensuite.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Si on ajoute à la fin de la phrases des bijoutiers  `Oui, il y en a des bijoutiers ` ca reste correcte la phrase.

Comment: Non, "en" sert à remplacer "des bijoutiers". Il ne faut mettre que l'un des deux ! *Oui, il y en a." ou "Oui, il y a des bijoutiers".

Comment: Pas tout à fait d'accord, "il y en a, des bijoutiers" insiste sur leur grand nombre

Comment: Effectivement, mais cette phrase n'est pas appropriée en réponse à une question. Elle se suffit à elle-même et comme elle n'a pas été initiée par une autre phrase, et que donc "des bijoutiers" n'a pas été énoncé préalablement, il faut préciser ensuite quel est le COD auquel "en" fait référence.

Answer (score 3):

COMPLÉMENT DE RÉPONSE
 1/ en tenant compte de la question plus étendue que @famas22 considère dans un commentaire (Si on remplace la phrase « Oui, il y en a. » par « Oui, il y en a des bijoutiers. » la phrase reste-t-elle correcte?.),
2/ en incluant la réponse de @Carnelune (1.), et
3/ en ajoutant le commentaire de @Eau qui dort (Pas tout à fait d'accord, "il y en a, des bijoutiers" insiste sur leur grand nombre) (2.)

1. Est-ce qu'il y a des bijoutiers au marché de Noël ?
   Oui, il y en a.
   Oui, il y en a deux.
2. Il y en a des bijoutiers dans cette rue!

*On exprime par cette tournure idiomatique **strictement de la langue parlée** un jugement sur le nombre des bijoutiers, ce jugement étant que le nombre est important.*

3. -- Ils se demandaient où trouver certains magasins, des horlogers, des orfèvres, des bijoutiers. On ne savait pas très bien et on leur a quand même indiqué la rue Sainte Catherine… Il y en a, des orfèvres, rue Sainte Catherine? 
   -- Il y a des bijoutiers, bien sûr, mais je ne sais pas s'il y aurait des orfèvres.

*Dans ce cas de **reprise** d'un terme déjà utilisé en plus de l'usage de « en » il est possible de se servir de façon non ambiguë de la forme normale, qui est formelle alors que celle qui inclut « en », bien qu'assez courante, n'est pas très formelle* : « Il y a des orfèvres dans la rue Sainte Catherine? » ou une autre forme courante comme « Est-ce qu'il y a des orfèvres rue Sainte Catherine? ». *Dans une telle énonciation certaines personnes peuvent ne pas marquer de pause avant et après « orfèvre » et on peut alors si l'on veut ne pas utiliser les virgules lorsque l'on reproduit ces paroles à l'écrit. Pourquoi cette forme est utilisé n'est pas clair, peut être par souci de conserver un lien avec ce qui a été dit (en). Il n'est pas nécessaire qu'un choix ait à être fait entre plusieurs éléments, comme ici « horloger/bijoutiers/orfèvres », il peut n'y en avoir qu'un; la reprise n'a pas alors une valeur très importante, le locuteur pense seulement devoir rappeler de quoi il s'agit.*

4. -- Cela fait des années que nous cherchons un philatéliste qui aurait cet ensemble de timbres; d'après certaines informations, il n'y a pratiquement pas de collectionneurs de timbres dans cette ville…
   -- Il y en a des philatélistes dans notre ville, plus que vous ne pensez!

*Ce type de reprise avec usage de « en » est utilisé pour annuler une assertion qui vient d'être faite et la phrase est souvent dite avec une intonation particulière. Ce n'est cependant pas la façon la plus formelle d'apporter un démenti à ce qui vient d'être dit; par exemple, « -- Détrompez-vous! Il y a des philatélistes dans notre ville, plus que vous ne pensez! » en plaçant une intonation emphatique sur le a de « il y a » est une façon au moins aussi effective d'accomplir cela, de plus que contester sa grammaire est hors de question.*